# Any rules regarding button order?

Tags: buttons, design, contextual-menu, order

I am currently designing a GUI that contains a FileSystem in form of a TreeView.

Everytime you rightclick a TreeItem you will get a menu that looks like this:

[image]

My Buttons are position like this atm: first Open, then New Directory, New File, Delete and last Upload.

I was wondering if there were any unwritten rules regarding button order, since this doesnt feel quiet right yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, when designing menus, you should optimize for speed. A well-designed menu reduces the time a user needs to find a particular menu item. A couple of helpful strategies, in descending order of preference:

1. Put **frequently used** options at the front. E.g., 'Open' in your case seems a logical option to put on top.
2. **Group** related items. Both 'new' menu items could be visually separated from the other options, for example by using separator lines.
3. Use **natural order**. If nothing else, you could use natural ordering (e.g., alphabetically). This allows users to quickly scan a list for the option they are looking for.